# Can I create site like multivendor ecommerce with react-native without website?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, express

I am planning to make a mobile application for my college. The site will use react-native in frontend and I want to learn and use node and express in backend. There are no MERN course for react-native.
Can I take a course for MERN (react course) and apply it in react native? Is Node and express same for react native like it is for REACT?

Comment: yes it is the same